# How to color both points and lines on mouseover in Vega Altair?

Tags: altair

In a Chart created with `mark_point() + mark_line()`, I want to hover the mouse over a line and highlight it with a color. Here's the code:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

cars = data.cars.url

sel_line = alt.selection_point(on="mouseover")

lines = alt.Chart(cars).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X("Weight_in_lbs:Q", bin=True, title="Peso em Libras"),
    y=alt.Y("average(Horsepower):Q"),
    color=alt.condition(sel_line, "Origin:N", alt.value("lightgray"))
).add_params(
    sel_line
)

points = alt.Chart(cars).mark_point().encode(
    x=alt.X("Weight_in_lbs:Q", bin=True),
    y=alt.Y("average(Horsepower):Q"),
    color=alt.condition(sel_line, "Origin:N", alt.value("lightgray")),
).add_params(
    sel_line
)

lines + points
```

[Chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM94s.png)

I wanted to hover the mouse over a line and color both the points and the line, but that doesn't happen with one selector. How do I do it?

Here's a pic of the current chart:

[Chart with highlighted line, but gray points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvRE4.png)